# Turn off sticky query params in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, query-string

I found a jsbin that illustrates my problem. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ucanam/2708.

That last link, where there are no explicit query-params set on the link-to, it uses the current sticky query param value on the controller. It there a way to turn this sticky feature off? Would doing so break other scenarios?

My current solution is to null out query params on every route I want cleared:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  deactivate: function() {
    var controller = this.controllerFor(this.get('controllerName'));
    var queryParams = controller.get('queryParams');
    for (var i = 0; i < queryParams.length; i++)
      controller.set(queryParams[i], null);
  }
});
```

This works but it seems like there should be an easier way.

I should note that doing something like `{{#link-to 'route' (query-params val=null)}}{{/link-to}}` for every route is not an option because I have some reusable code where the route is a variable, so I won't know the query params I have to null out.

#### Edit:

Here is the proper way to do it, in case the doc's from the answer change:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  resetController: function(controller, isExiting) {
    if (isExiting) {
      var queryParams = controller.get('queryParams');
      for (var i = 0; i < queryParams.length; i++)
        controller.set(queryParams[i], null);
    }
  }
});
```

#### Edit 2:

It's now very easy to do this via this addon https://github.com/kellyselden/ember-query-params-reset. It also resets to the original values, not just nulling out values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gives you two options for how to handle this in the guides: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/query-params/#toc_sticky-query-param-values

Looks like option #2 is pretty close to what you are doing:

> use the Route.resetController hook to set query param values back to their defaults before exiting the route or changing the route's model.

Comment: link is 404. Please post answers explaining how to solve the problem rather than just linking the docs.